# How Can I Perform MySql Insertions After A Paypal Checkout

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, paypal

Recently I built a website where the user fills in a form and then goes to a checkout page they then press the pay with paypal button and then are taken to the paypal checkout, Then in the paypal button settings I have them taken the user to a php script where it inserts the info to the server via mysql then instantly taken to a thank you page.

At least that's what I want to happen; the page doesn't seem to do anything and when testing it out I echoed one of the variables and it doesn't show up so I gathered that the cookies aren't remembered or something of the sort, although I don't know why this is happening

I'm simply lost on whats going on and my scripts definitely work as before I didn't connect the button and when clicked it did all the correct orders however when the paypal checkout confirmation directs the user it doesn't seem to work

I have seen a few threads on this however never saw a concrete conclusion however apologies if this has been covered

Appreciate any advice or help immensely and thank anyone in advance,

Cheers

Comment: You really need to read the PayPal SDK and follow it exactly.

Comment: Cheeeers Jeffff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To guarantee your server is notified of when a transaction completes, I recommend using this server-side integration demo as a skeleton:

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Notice that there is no PayPal transaction created until the line that reads:

```
fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/'
```

This would be doing an XHR to a PHP script on your server (at that sample path), which **must itself then call the PayPal API** to capture the transaction.

This server-side design guarantees that your server will be notified of all completed transactions at capture time, so it can then immediately write the required record to your mysql database.

---

If instead you used a different type of integration, such as a client-side one, e.g. as shown here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Your server would not be guaranteed to be notified of captured transactions, since the capture happens via JS in the client web browser.